# Non-input field in Symfony form generator?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a field in my database that auto generate and show for user as read only / text.

How can I have a widget that will output only the text value of that field without put it into a `<input>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a read-only input element, in your form class (configure method) write:

```
$this->widgetSchema['<field name>']->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

On the other hand, you can show only field value. Use `$form->getObject()->get<field name>` for this needs. In this case, you need to customize you form. See [The Display Customization](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers). Don't forget to unset field in your form (`unset($this['<field name>'])`).